# Undefined variable: _SESSION on new WAMP setup

Tags: php, session

I'm getting the error below whenever I try to access session variables:

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

I have a session_start() command at the top of my login page (but not on any other pages).

This is on a new WAMP setup on a Windows 2003 Server, so I suspect that I may not have configured the server correctly for session management.
Apart from the setting below, is there anything else that I need to do to enable sessions?

```
[Session]
session.save_path = "1;c:\inetpub\wwwroot"
```

Comment: gah.. don't put your session files into the document root. that's a hideous security problem. they have to be somewhere OUTSIDE the document root, and you have to ensure the server id (IUSR_IIS?) has 'change' permissions on that folder + files.

Comment: +1 for @MarcB. Also, you have to have `session_start()` at the top of ***every*** page.

Comment: `$_SESSION` wouldn't it? Long not done PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a session_start() command at the top of my login page (but not
>   on any other pages).

Well you should. You need to call `session_start()` on each connection that will use `$_SESSION` array, not only on login.

Comment: If I put a session start at the top of every page I get "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()" - and still can't query the session vars. I also checked and variables_order is set to "GPCS"

Answer (score -2):

Put your `session_start()` command and any database connections in a separate php file and just include it on all your pages.

Comment: Exactly how does this help the OP with their problem?

Comment: @MarcB given OP does call `session_start()` only on login page, that's pretty valid answer.